# Synonym for Crowdsourcing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Describing that we *(as systems' owners)* can leverage users' capabilities to do something useful unpaid, what's the best word/expression for?

I'm looking for something rather than Crowdsourcing.

Comment: [User-generated content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-generated_content)?

Comment: Not necessarily content, in fact anything such as labeling images, solving tests, etc.

Comment: I'd have thought user base/crowdsourced image labels and "test solutions" fall well within UGC - *content* means all *stuff [information] of value/interest*.

Comment: You expect this content to be *contributed by the community* or a  *community contribution*

Comment: What don't you like about _crowdsourcing_? Understanding why you want a different word may help identify the correct word or phrase to recommend.

Comment: In fact, Crowdsourcing is the most appropriate word that describe such kind of situation/action. However, due to its overusing by others, I want to use another word/expression to refer that.

Comment: _crowdsourcing_ is a relatively new coinage. It was coined precisely because there was no good synonym!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, as I just found, the most appropriate synonym for crowdsourcing is **Human(-based) Computation**.

Comment: If you were addressing the anticipated (and unpaid) crowd source, you could call it "Something (for us) for nothing (for you)."

Comment: Then you were not looking for a synonym for "crowdsourcing", you were looking for a synonym for "unpaid, crowdsourced **software**" (There are many other activities that can be crowdsourced, paid or unpaid) I suggest you revise your question Title accordingly.

Comment: I'm not looking for any software. As quoted in my answer (and comments), CAPTCHA is a good example of such kind that its inventor knew it as a type of crowdsourcing. Moreover, since users have to pass those tests to use the service, it's in fact unpaid.

Answer (score 1):

If your target is something more than just content how about a `collaborative environment`?

Comment: It seems appropriate, however how **collaboration** implies unpaidness? It's an important part for the context.

Comment: Do you need to specify that it is unpaid *in that phrase*? Can you say so later?

Comment: In fact users are not aware that they are doing something specific! For example, such as Google reCAPTCHA that takes benefit of users to digitize books.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate answer that I just found is Human-based computation (also Human computation):

> **Human-based computation** (HBC), **human-assisted computation**,**ubiquitous human computing** or **distributed thinking** (by analogy to distributed computing) is a computer science technique in which a machine performs its function by *outsourcing certain steps to humans*, usually as microwork. This approach uses differences in abilities and alternative costs between humans and computer agents to achieve symbiotic human-computer interaction. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-based_computation))

And another evidence from Luis von Ahn, a well-known scientist from [CMU](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/):

> I build systems that *combine humans and computers to solve large-scale problems* that neither can solve alone. I call this **Human Computation**, but others sometimes call it **Crowdsourcing**. Some of my past projects include: CAPTCHA, The ESP Game (acquired by Google), GWAP, and reCAPTCHA (acquired by Google).

Last Edit : **[Collective Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intelligence)** is another synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Mind meld, group think, 42 heads are better than one,
human cloud (or cloud of humanity), hive mind.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me you want to foster volunteerism on some kind of social networking platform. So, you might want to call it something like a ***Internet community service platform***.